# rails - how can I show a page's HTML source in the debugger with a request spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, shoulda

I've tried `p page` and `p page.source` and also:

```
(rdb:1) find ('page')
(rdb:1) find ('bosy')
(rdb:1) find ('body')
(rdb:1) find
(rdb:1) p page
(rdb:1) p html
(rdb:1) p source
(rdb:1) p page.source
```

but all I get is variations on:

```
*** Unknown command: "page".  Try "help".
```

Code:

```
describe "For a user who is not logged in." do

  context "Visiting the home page." do
    before(:each) { visit root_path }

    describe "The page." do
      subject { page }

      debugger
      1   

      it "Has a 'login' link." do
        should have_link('Sign In')
      end 

      it "does NOT have a 'logout' link." do
        should have_no_link('Logout')
      end 

    end 

  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where your current `debugger` line is won't get executed in the scope where `page` is defined.  Maybe `before(:each) { visit root_path; debugger }` would work.  Completely untested.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. I can't answer your question, but if you goal is to peek at the page, 
you could use

save_and_open_page

which requires the launchy gem in test & development scope.

(assuming you're using capybara?)

Comment: +1 Not the answer I was looking for but this info is useful for others.